# Are archive-links allowed?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

A way to bypass paywall to journals and other online publications is internet archive.

Are these links allowed on Skeptics?

Pro:

- Enable access for everyone to check if the quote/reference is valid.

Con:

- It's stealing (in spirit if not by law)

Comment: I asked a similar question on MSE a couple of years back, but received no reply: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375360/461068

Answer (score 3):

We are not judging copyright, it's far too complex an issue. Especially as a lot of what we do arguably falls under "fair use".

I don't see any reason to prohibit internet archive links, as long as the original link is also present in the post. They are a useful addition for questions particularly as they cannot be changed, so potential later corrections that could cause confusion would be obvious.

Comment: I would add that we frequently use IA links when the original source is no longer available, so we certainly don't have a blanket prohibition against it.